# Animation/Transition-Creator for iOS/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, transition

Together with an illustrator I want to create some screens with lots of animations/transitions (moving sprites). I need the illustrator to do the animation. He knows how to use AfterEffects so best would be some kind of timeline-tool to create the transitions/scalings/alphas etc.

My question is now: Is there some kind of tool out there that could be used to create animations and then export the used parameters to objective-c to import it to xcode?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Flash2Cocos2D](https://github.com/TheDamArmada/Flash2Cocos2D) and I think this is the best solution available right now.
Also promissing: [cocosbuilder](http://cocosbuilder.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge: No.

We spend some time a couple of months back trying to find something similar to Expression blend, just for iOS, but without luck.

If you however are planing to make your app for MacOS and not iOS you can take a look at [quartz composer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Composer). For iOS you could also take a look at storyboard ([here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=219) is a link to fairly good tutorial), but I'm afraid your needs will not be met by the features of storyboard.

Comment: look what I have added as answer - maybe you could use this, too!

Comment: Looks promising. I will investigate it when I have the time and/or need:-) Thanks.